# Orthogonality of positron/electron Dirac spinors with different momenta?

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors

Consider the Dirac spinor for a positron at rest, and the spinor for an electron with non-zero 3-momentum. In the Dirac basis it is clear that these are not orthogonal, as I would expect. Does this have a physical interpretation?

Of course the full states are orthogonal, but I would expect the spinors to be orthogonal also.

When I refer to spinors in this question, I mean the spacetime-independent object.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you expect the spinors to be orthogonal?

Recall, for a vanishing electromagnetic field, the Pauli equation collapses to
$$(\hat p ^2 /2m -i\hbar \partial_t )|\psi\rangle=0,$$
solved by
$$|()\rangle = \exp(−^2t/2ℏ)|(0)\rangle  .
$$
This is a pure tensor product state of a momentum space (unnormalizable) wave function  ⊗ a spinor, which does not change at all, so it dots to itself, to yield 1 , if normalized. The dotting of  your two wavefunctions dots each of its tensor factors in the respective space. Dotting 1 to an exponential, however, will readily yield zero for $p\neq 0$.

What's weird about that?

Comment: Sure, the whole states are orthogonal, as I said. But it seems worth thinking about that the boosted electron spinor has a nonzero projection onto the positron rest spinor, while the two particles at rest have orthogonal spinors. If you have a physical interpretation of this, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: I've no idea what puzzles you. You take a spin up electron at rest, and boost it in the z direction to something that's still spin up and has a nonzero momentum. Without spin, you may rotate (analogously to a boost) a state to  an orthogonal state.